# Getting P-value of test; statistics

Tags: probability, statistics

In order to test $H_0 : \mu = 50$ vs $H_{\text{a}} : \mu \neq 50$, a random sample of 9 observations
(from a normally distributed population) is obtained, yielding $\bar{x} = 61$ and $s = 21$.
What is the P-value of the test?

(a) greater than 0.1

(b) between 0.05 and 0.10

(c) between 0.01 and 0.05

(d) less than 0.01.

I got Z value of $1.57$. How do i convert this into P-value?

Comment: What have you done so far first write that down coz this isn't that hard to calculate just google it.

Answer (score 0):

The way to approach these types of problem is the following. We begin by noting that we can calculate the $z$-value as follows:

$$z=\frac{\bar{x}-\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}=\frac{61-50}{7}=1.5714$$

And therefore we have that (using tables or an appropriate online tool):

$$\mathbb{P}[Z<z]=\Phi(z)\approx 0.9420$$

Thus the $p$-value of this two-tailed test is given by:

$$\frac{1-\Phi(z)}{2}\approx 0.0290$$

Comment: You used the wrong procedure for this test type. This test should be two-tailed.

Comment: @Ian Thanks, I missed that!